# Selenium XPATH: Iterate through child elements with different class names

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I want to iterate through child elements of parent `<div class="_1LiCn">`. Access the child element, extract some information and move on to next child element.

[image]

Unable to loop all the elements since the child class name changes.
**Suggest an alternative to achieve this**

```
pack_sizes_elements =  wd.find_element(By.XPATH , "//div[@class = '_2Z6Vt   _3vDTQ rippleEffect']")
for element in pack_sizes_elements:
     #MRP 
     mrp =  element.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[@data-qa ='productPrice']").text.strip()
```

Comment: The url can't be opened

Comment: @Prophet try this https://business.bigbasket.com/pd/40127506/aashirvaad-shudh-chakki-atta-5-kg/?nc=cl-prod-list&t_pg=&t_p=&t_s=cl-prod-list&t_pos=1&t_ch=desktop. Structure is same assume different class name

Comment: The same problem. 403 Error Occured. URL can't be opened

Comment: @Prophet Can't you help without using URL. Assuming xyz names for different child classes

Comment: Looks like the class names here are dynamic so we need to find fixed locators. To do so I need to see the actual page itself or all it HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath expression `//div[@class='_1LiCn']/div` will create the desired   iterable list of elements

```
pack_sizes_elements =  wd.find_elements(By.XPATH , "//div[@class='_1LiCn']/div")
for element in pack_sizes_elements:
     #MRP 
     mrp =  element.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//td[@data-qa ='productPrice']").text.strip()
```